# Snowflake `not in` and `in` clauses producing the same results?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that contains order ids. I am collecting an export from a source system of order ids and need to find which ones are missing from my table. I have two queries

## NOT IN Query

Identifies ids not in table

```
with provided_ids (ids) as (
Select 'fu' Union All 
Select 'bar' Union All 
Select 'latin' Union All 
Select 'stuff')
select p.ids from provided_ids p
where p.ids not in (select distinct a.order_id from table1 o where p.ids = o.order_id)
```

## IN Query

Identifies ids in table

```
select distinct order_id
from
client_brcc.platform.vw_order_history
where source_order_id in ('fu', 'bar', 'latin', 'stuff')
```

The issue I am running into is there are ids that will appear in both results. Something fishy is happening with my `NOT IN` query but after testing I still an not able to figure it out. Any advice?

Ive tried removing the `DISTINCT` from the subquery of the `NOT IN` query but the reults were the same. Ive also searched for spaces and other factors but the ids are listed the same for both queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query:

```
with provided_ids (ids) as (
Select 'fu' Union All 
Select 'bar' Union All 
Select 'latin' Union All 
Select 'stuff')
select p.ids from provided_ids p
where p.ids not in (select distinct a.order_id from table1 o where p.ids = o.order_id)
```

=>

```
with provided_ids (ids) as (
    Select 'fu' Union All 
    Select 'bar' Union All 
    Select 'latin' Union All 
    Select 'stuff')
select p.ids 
from provided_ids p
where p.ids not in (select o.order_id from table1 o where o.order_id IS NOT NULL);
```

or by using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
with provided_ids (ids) as (
  Select 'fu' Union All 
  Select 'bar' Union All 
  Select 'latin' Union All 
  Select 'stuff')
select p.ids 
from provided_ids p
where NOT EXISTS (select o.order_id from table1 o where p.ids = o.order_id)
```